# Python - Access nested class data from another nested class

Tags: python, class

For example, I have the following code:

```py
class Webpage:
  class Properties:
    STYLE = 'attribute="value"'

  class Components:
    SOME_TAG = f'<tag {Properties.STYLE} />'

print(Webpage.Components.SOME_TAG)
```

- Then I get the error: `Line 6 [...] NameError: name 'Properties' is not defined`.
- If I change `Properties.STYLE` with `Webpage.Properties.STYLE` I get the error: `Line 6 [...] NameError: name 'Webpage' is not defined` (expected, because `Webpage` is still getting defined).

Why the first error occurs? `Properties` is already defined. How can I get the expected behavior? My real code is different, but I only want to know why this happens and how can I access a nested class variable (or function) from another nested class.

Comment: *Typically* you don't have nested classes in Python. out of curiosity what's your use-case?

Comment: The error message doesn't match the code. The code says `Components`, the error says `Properties`. Please post the actual code and error message.

Comment: Here's a tutorial on using nested classes: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/inner-classes-python

Comment: @Barmar It's the actual code, the full error message is:
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "page.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Webpage:
  File "page.py", line 5, in Webpage
    class Components:
  File "page.py", line 6, in Components
    SOME_TAG = f'<tag {Properties.STYLE} />'
NameError: name 'Properties' is not defined
```
`NameError` is at the end, it occurs inside `class Components` declaration.

Comment: `class` statements create namespaces, but not scopes. Since `Properties` isn't defined in the body of the `class Components` statement, the next place to look is the global scope, not the body of the enclosing `class` statement.

Comment: @That1Guy I want to create a library with constants for my developer mates. We can use properties or a whole made component. During development, we want to do massive changes in some properties for testing.
We want to use this logic for HTML components and Xpath expressions.

Comment: @AntoniodelaCruzCarrillo What role do nested classes play, tough?

Comment: Just because a web page *has* properties doesn't mean the *definition* of a property is part of the definition of a web page.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the object initializer or a static method. If you wanted a class attribute, I think you would need to mess around with meta classes. Below is how to use either static method or object initializer.

```
class Webpage:
  class Properties:
    STYLE = 'attribute="value"'

  class Components:
    @staticmethod
    def some_tag():
      return f'<tag {Webpage.Properties.STYLE} />'

    def __init__(self):
      self.SOME_TAG = self.some_tag()

c = Webpage.Components()
print(Webpage.Components.some_tag())
print(c.SOME_TAG)
```

Prints:
`<tag attribute="value" />`
`<tag attribute="value" />`